# Splitting txt file into multiple based on custom delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, split, delimiter

I have a txt file with around 100 multiple-choice questions. I want to split them into 100  txt files containing one question. The delimiter will be "number.", example - 1. for the first question, 2. for next like this. the issue is a "number." can emerge amidst a question also, so that can be checked by ensuring that "(d)" was encountered prior to that "number.".

```
Sample text -
1.Consider the following statements with regard to the State Council of Ministers:1. The constitution specifies the size of the state council of ministers and the ranking of ministers.2.The advice tendered by the ministers to the Governor shall not be inquired into in any court. Which of the statements given above is/ are correct? (a)1 only(b)2 only(c)Both 1 and 2(d)Neither 1 nor 22.Consider the following statements with reference to Public Accounts Committee:1. The committee was set up under the provisions of the Government of India Act1919.2.Speaker is the ex- Officio Chairman of the committee. A minister cannot be a member of the committee. Which of the statements given above is/are not correct? (a)1 only(b)2 and 3 only(c)1 and 2 only(d)2 only
```

The text is like mentioned above, and it should be split like this -

1.Consider the following statements with regard to the State Council of Ministers:1. The constitution specifies the size of the state council of ministers and the ranking of ministers.2.The advice tendered by the ministers to the Governor shall not be inquired into in any court. Which of the statements given above is/ are correct? (a)1 only(b)2 only(c)Both 1 and 2(d)Neither 1 nor 2

2.Consider the following statements with reference to Public Accounts Committee:1. The committee was set up under the provisions of the Government of India Act1919.2.Speaker is the ex- Officio Chairman of the committee. A minister cannot be a member of the committee. Which of the statements given above is/are not correct? (a)1 only(b)2 and 3 only(c)1 and 2 only(d)2 only

Comment: Maybe [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) is what you're looking for? Maybe with an expression like `r'^\d+\.'`. That expression looks for a start of a line, then looks for one or more digits, followed by a literal dot (.).

Comment: But there are number and . in between the questions as well. Different statements of the ques have 1., 2., type stuff. It needs to check the (d) identifier and then apply the number. delimiter.
Thank you very much for your response, btw. I didnt expect such quick efforts, 1st post on stack.

Comment: Are the questions you're trying to split not on their own separate lines?

Comment: Ok, I have put the sample text in code format. thanks.

Comment: How can you tell that 2 is part of the string before and that it should start with `2.` instead of `22.` in this part `Neither 1 nor 22.Consider` ?

Comment: Yeah I understand. Looks like I need better pdf2text tool first. Its a two column pdf and that is why the formatting is a bit ugly in text file.